# Calling a PHP function from Ajax in Google App Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

Hi I have a problem on calling a php function from ajax but the return is the html script. I used CI for my framework.

For example in my view page i have :

```
          $.ajax({
            url:"/home/loginUser",
            type:"post",
            dataType: "json",               
            success: function(result){
                alert(result.result);
            }
          })
```

and in my **controller** I have :

```
function loginUser(){
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $response =  array(
            'result'    => false
        );
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

But the response is always the whole script on my view file.

Comment: Are you using some form of automated templating on the controller that has the loginUser action? If you are, try adding an exit at the end of the function, or disable templating for that action.

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml file? Thanks.